# Unknown directive type "toctree". Error in Pycharm, but index.html works

Tags: pycharm, python-sphinx, preview, autodoc, toctree

When working in PyCharm, the preview mode of the document I am creating in Sphinx shows:

> ```sh
> System Message: ERROR/3 (<stdin>, line 9)
>
> Unknown directive type "toctree".
>
> ..toctree::
>  :maxdepth: 2
>
> file1
> file2
> ```

I have included the `autodoc` extension in my conf.py file. When I open the /build/index.html file, it works fine however. My question thus is: How can I remove this error from the PyCharm preview mode, so that I can preview my document without having to open the /build/index.html file all the time?

Comment: Sphinx is built on top of the Docutils library. The `toctree` directive works with Sphinx, but not with only Docutils. The PyCharm previewer does not use Sphinx; it probably uses the Docutils [rst2html.py](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/user/tools.html#rst2html-py) tool. See https://grokbase.com/t/python/python-list/086kaqv52v/docutils-rst2html-py-gives-error-3-unknown-directive-type-toctree.

Comment: @mzjn Thanks, I got a similar problem and then found out that the community edition does not have this feature.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Sphinx is built on top of the Docutils library. The `toctree` directive works with Sphinx, but it is not recognized by Docutils.

The PyCharm previewer does not use Sphinx (this is true for the free community edition and for Professional editions as of 2019); it likely uses [rst2html.py](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/user/tools.html#rst2html-py) from Docutils.

This mailing list thread is about the same error: https://web.archive.org/web/20180715103227/https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2008-June/493826.html