# ".. note::" and ".. deprecated::" annotations are not recognized by PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, python-sphinx, docstring, deprecation-warning

I set my PyCharm to use reStructured docstring format, however it does not recognize `.. note::` or `.. deprecated::`. And by that I mean when you hover over the method which has such annotations, it shows them as plain text. Whereas, in case of `:param` and `:return:`, a separate section with different font is shown.

Another minor issue is that two consecutive dots are picked by the spelling checker.

Is this a limitation of PyCharm or do I need to use specific configurations?

Setting PyCharm: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/settings-tools-python-integrated-tools.html
Deprecation Annotation: https://deprecated.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sphinx_deco.html

Comment: The vendor asks you to report such https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/reporting-issues.html

Comment: `.. note::` and `.. deprecated::` are Sphinx directives (not defined by Docutils):  https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/directives.html. They are not recognized by PyCharm AFAIK. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/57411560/407651.

Comment: Docutils defines reStructuredText directives as "two periods and a space, followed by the directive type and two colons". So regardless of if `.. note::` is a known marker or not, it should be possible for PyCharm to differentiate it from plain text. 
https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/directives.html

Comment: If the remaining problem is "two consecutive dots are picked by the spelling checker", then that should be posted as a separate question IMHO.